# can someone explain where the "g_io_create_watch" definiton is?

Tags: c, glib

I was analysing how GIOchannel, glib source code. can someone explain.

```
GSource * g_io_create_watch (GIOChannel   *channel,GIOCondition  condition){

  g_return_val_if_fail (channel != NULL, NULL);
  return channel->funcs->io_create_watch (channel, condition); //THIS LINE

}
```

"THIS LINE" above mean?
I tried to find out for which function it is pointing to, but didn't understand.
The function is there in file  giochannel.c of glib source code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't match the title at all. But what this line does is call a function pointer; you should check what type `GIOChannel.funcs` has, then check out the `io_create_watch` member on that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library GIO uses object-oriented techniches but written in plain C.

Now, to the point:

- `channel`: is a pointer to a `GIOChannel` object. That's easy.
- `channel->funcs`: is a pointer to the virtual table of this `GIOChannel` object. That is, a struct of pointers to functions. The idea is that there may be several implementations of `GIOChannel`, each of them with a diferent table of functions that implements that specific class.
- `channel->funcs->io_create_watch`: is the implementation of the `g_io_create_watch` function for that `GIOChannel` object.
- `return channel->funcs->io_create_watch (channel, condition)`: this expression calls the relevant given virtual function and returns the returned value.

As you can see the public function `g_io_create_watch` simply forwards the call to the corresponding virtual function. That is necessary because in GObject virtual functions are never considered public, that is, client code should never call them directly.

To see how this works, take a look to the specific implementations of some of these functions, for example, for a plain Unix file, see the `giounix.c` file, particularly the function `g_io_channel_unix_new` and the struct `unix_channel_funcs`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it returns a pointer to a GSource type, which looks to be a function pointer.